# How to identify the faulty driver if the computer working good in safe mode?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, crash, safe-mode

I had 64bit windows 10 computer, it then suddenly started BSOD. I tried everything in the internet but nothing solves the problem, so I just reformatted the pc and go back to windows 7. Everything went well, until I installed web browser. Everytime I open a web browser, again it turns BSOD again collecting crash dump. It works perfectly fine in safe mode. So I tried to change the RAM. It then again went very well. Everythings working fine. I was able to surf the net install and download applications. So I thought everything's is fine already until the next day, everytime I open any application that uses internet, it again went to BSOD collecting crash dump.

Are there any explanation what might causes this BSOD?

**---UPDATE----**

I tried the whocrashed software and based on the dump file, it might be driver issue.

[image]

Is there a way to locate which driver is causing a problem?Because I was able to surf in safe mode with networking.

[This](https://www.sendspace.com/file/may89c) is the dump files.

**---Update prt 2---**

So, as per suggestion this might be hardware issue so I tried other hard drive and same thing happens, but this time, BSOD happens when logging in.

What's wrong with this computer????

Comment: This sounds hard to answer accurately, and I suspect hardware (even if not RAM).

Comment: Please ZIP up your last five or so minidump files (they're in c:\windows\minidump), upload them to a file sharing site, and post a link. If your system is configured to write larger dump files, please include that too (by default it's in c:\windows\memory.dmp ).

Comment: @Jamie Hanrahan. Dump files are added. Thanks.

Comment: Don't thank me yet. minidumps often don't have enough info to pin things down. Heck, even full dumps are often not definitive. But I or someone here will look at them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a driver issue. Your CPU (L2 Cache - `GCACHEL2_ERR_ERR`) is damaged:

```
1: kd> !errrec fffffa80043c3028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ fffffa80043c3028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d2a3a2169ca603
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 3/23/2017 6:56:23 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa80043c30a8
Section       @ fffffa80043c3180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Generic
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 2
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000306a9
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000001

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa80043c30f0
Section       @ fffffa80043c3240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000001
CPU Id        : a9 06 03 00 00 08 10 01 - bf e3 9a 3d ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ fffffa80043c3240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa80043c3138
Section       @ fffffa80043c32c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : GCACHEL2_ERR_ERR (Proc 1 Bank 5)
  Status      : 0xbe2000000005110a
  Address     : 0x0000000025ac4280
  Misc.       : 0x0000031084000086
```

Windbg only shows generic Cache error, so we can't see in detail what it wrong. Replace the CPU with a new one.

Comment: Thanks mate. I've been trying to resolve this in a week. Thinking that it's just a software. I just wander why is it working perfectly fine in "safe mode with networking"

Comment: in safe mode less programs run and which causes less L2 Cache access so here you may not see it

Comment: This *is* a driver problem: https://superuser.com/questions/1641725/starting-my-kernel-driver-startservice-results-in-0x124-bluescreen-due-to-a-ma

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it's a driver problem. More like hardware.

- Make sure that none of the hardware components are overclocked.
- Make sure that the machine is adequately cooled - check CPU and GPU temperatures  If in doubt, open the PC case and finger-test. Make sure that fans spin and the actual cooler is in contact with the CPU/GPU.
- Do a RAM test with memtestx86. Unreliable RAM is many times the cause of this error.
- Do a HDD check with HDTune (works in safemode).
- Update the motherboard BIOS according to the manufacturer's instructions to the latest version.
- Clean and carefully remove any dust from the inside of the machine, specially on memory modules contacts.
- If all the above fails, start removing items of hardware one-by-one in the hope that the broken part is something non-essential which can be removed (PCI-E cards, other things connected to USB or other ports, ODD, etc).
- If all hardware is fine and you still get the error, do a clean install of Windows.

Comment: I don't know how to check yet if the components are overclocked, I'd tested two different ram and same thing happen. I also tried other HDD also same thing happen in different scenarion. ButI would like to try this out and update you. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: You can reset the BIOS (or enter BIOS and load defaults) and if there were overclocking settings they will revert to defaults.

Comment: his cpu is gone. dump shows L2 cache error

Comment: That can be caused by Over-clocking. If it's not OCed, it's indeed damaged.