# BSOD: BlueScreenView says it's NTFS.sys

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

I've been getting a lot of blue screens recently. I started to get them in my previous system (Windows 7) some 10 days ago and decided I might as well clean install Windows 10 on my PC.
I've got an SSD and an HD. They were both formatted and then I partitioned my HD in two: one would be getting the non-essential program installations, and the other general files (say pics, videos, etc). I then clean installed Windows 10 into the SSD.

During the installation I had to convert the partition style on the SSD from GPT to MBR, and it all worked smoothly. I got Windows 10 up and running, activated it, but the BSODs just kept coming.
I've just now done a Windows 10 'fresh start', which seems to be a sort of official Windows reinstallation, albeit not a clean one. Still the BSODs keep coming.

I've searched for some solution, and while none so far have worked, I found that BlueScreenView seems to be a good tool for debugging these. This is the first crash since I've downloaded it, so here I am.
Now, I'm no super computer savvy and don't really understand what these dumps mean. I was hoping someone could help me understand them or otherwise point me in a direction that could solve these BSODs.
I have included [a zipped folder here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmVHY36R4ahUmlPVOy7fhEJ1yhZ5) with various files that might help someone more knowledgeable than me understand what's happening.

Thank you very much

---

I've decided to use WinDbg Preview as suggested by Ramhound in the comments.
It says

> *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for win32k.sys
>   Probably caused by : NTFS.sys ( NTFS!NtfsFreeFcbUsnRecord+784aa )

I just had another BSOD, and this time I got

> *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for win32k.sys
>   Probably caused by : ntkrnlmp.exe ( nt!SmHpBufferProtectEx+ea )

BlueScreenView does not say NTFS.sys was the culprit this time, but ntoskrnl.exe shows up in red in both dumps.

---

My latest BSOD has

> BugCheck 124, {0, ffffa80ca8b40028, be200000, 11152}
>   Probably caused by : GenuineIntel

Maybe it's something to do with the processors?

---

Following magicandre1981's suggestion, here are the errrec results for my dump:

```
6: kd> !errrec ffffcb84ecd2c028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffcb84ecd2c028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d387e96641ab55
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 1/7/2018 22:29:01 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffcb84ecd2c0a8
Section       @ ffffcb84ecd2c180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Instruction Execute
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 2
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000206a7
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000006

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffcb84ecd2c0f0
Section       @ ffffcb84ecd2c240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000006
CPU Id        : a7 06 02 00 00 08 10 06 - bf e3 9a 1f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffffcb84ecd2c240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffcb84ecd2c138
Section       @ ffffcb84ecd2c2c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : ICACHEL2_IRD_ERR (Proc 6 Bank 8)
  Status      : 0xbe20000000011152
  Address     : 0x0000000151e23540
  Misc.       : 0x000000702703c086
```

Comment: This particular program is notoriously known for given the wrong reason for a crash.  Windbg is much more efficient.  Plenty of questions with answers which go into specific details how to use it though

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: 0x124 = HW issue. the dump is not really helpful. run **chkdsk /F** to detect and fix NTFS issues

Comment: @magicandre1981 I think it's the processor. I've clean installed Windows, and then stress tested the CPU with Prime95 and I get either a failure on the test, or a BSOD (which WinDbg says is probably caused by GenuineIntel). At this point I've come to terms with the fact that my i7-2600k is in fact quite old, and I'm already shopping around for a replacement.

Comment: open the ump of the 0x124 crash and use [errrec command in Windbg](https://superuser.com/a/1191998/174557) to see which cpu issue Windbg shows

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've updated the question with results from the errrec command. I think my CPU's done :(

Comment: have you done overclocking to the i7k? this could cause issues. also look if there is a BIOS update.

Comment: I haven't. I will look for a BIOS update when I get home.

Comment: Well, I did it yesterday, but still got a BSOD later. In any case, I've already ordered other components. If you wish, you can post an answer and I'll accept it -- you've helped me some even if it turned out there wasn't much to be done.

Comment: no, I marked it as duplicate. both question deal with CPU issues and how to detect them.